# Update component's instance props / style

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I know this kind of manipulations might be unrecommended but in my situation I cannot find any other solution. I have a reference to component instance and I want to reach its parent, update style and re-render.
If you think this is crazy I'll describe the problem.

I am using section list with sticky header and it generates tree like this (simplified):

```js
<VirtualizedList>
    <CellRenderer> //internal component rendered by Virtualized list with flex: 1
        <MyComponent ref=(instance) => changeStylesFunc(instance) />
    </CellRenderer>
</VirtualizedList>
```

I am passing `MyComponent` but event if i set its style to `width: 80` wrapper (CellRenderer) will have full width because of its own styles.
T cannot change `CellRenderer`style because that would involve RN source code changes.

My idea:
since I have ref to `MyComponent` instance I can also reach parent instance (`CellRenderer`) by:

`const cellRenderer = ref._reactInternalInstance._currentElement._owner`

and I am stuck here because I had no luck with updating styles for `cellRenderer`.

What I've tried:

```js
cellRenderer._instance.props.styles = { width: 80 };
cellRenderer._currentElement.props.styles = { width: 80 };
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html):

> Often, several components need to reflect the same changing data. We
>   recommend lifting the shared state up to their closest common
>   ancestor. Let’s see how this works in action.

In your case, `<CellRenderer />` and `<MyComponent />` need to reflect the same changing data.

```js
class MyCell extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cellStyle: { flex: 1 }
    }
  }

  changeStyleFunc(newStyle) {
    this.setState({ cellStyle: newStyle });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <CellRenderer style={this.state.cellStyle}>
        <MyComponent onChangeStyle={(newStyle) => changeStylesFunc(newStyle)} />
      </CellRenderer>
    );
  }
}
```

So you can use:

```js
<VirtualizedList>
  ...
  <MyCell />
  ...
</VirtualizedList>
```

Note:

Don't mess up by modifying props from `ref` like that. It won't work, since [**An update can be caused by changes to props or state**](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating). Not by changing their inner, immutable value.

Comment: Umm maybe I didn't state that clearly - `CellRenderer` is a wrapper that `VirtualizedList` adds to each list element automatically. I cannot change it, I cannot wrap it with anything like `MyCell`. This is RN mechanism, not something that I customized.

Comment: yes you can, wrap it up should not be a problem. Have you tried it?

Comment: Well I think you should take a look inside rendering `VirtualizedList` in RN then we can talk about mechanisms :) EVEN if I'll wrap `CellRenderer` with `MyCell` while rendering `VirtualizedList` will wrap it with original `CellRenderer` again..

Comment: @MSadura I thought you're using `<VirturalizedList />` directly...If I'm not misunderstood, you used `<SectionList />`, and see `<VirturalizedList />` through inspector.

Comment: If that's the case, from document `<SectionList />` which said: *it's just a convenience wrapper around <VirtualizedList>*, state that you can use `<VirturalizedList />` directly without problem.  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html

Comment: @MSadura give another answer with code and pic, shows how to make it work with pure SectionList. hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to change visual width from `<SectionList />` items, without touching `<VisualizedList />` at all.

### Result:

[image]

### Code:

```js
export class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  getUidFromSectionAndRow(section, row) {
    return `${section}_${row}`;
  }
  getStyleWithUid(uid) {
    return this.state[uid] || {flex: 1};
  }
  setStyleWithUid(uid, style) {
    this.setState({
      [uid]: style
    });
  }

  render() {
    let sectionData = [
      [1,2,3],
      [1,2,3]
    ]

    return (
      <SectionList
        renderItem={({item}) => {
          return (
            <View style={[this.getStyleWithUid(item.key), {flexDirection: 'row', marginVertical: 10}]}>
              <Text style={{flex: 1, textAlign: 'center', textAlignVertical: 'center', backgroundColor: 'white'}}>This is number {item.value} row.</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                this.setStyleWithUid(item.key, {width: 200});
              }}>
                <Text style={{width: 80, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'purple', textAlign: 'center', textAlignVertical: 'center', color: 'white'}}>Change Width</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          )
        }}
        renderSectionHeader={ ({section}) => <Text style={{fontSize: 20, fontWeight: '600'}}>{section.title}</Text> }
          sections={
            [
              { data: [
                {
                  key: this.getUidFromSectionAndRow(1, 1),
                  value: 1
                },
                {
                  key: this.getUidFromSectionAndRow(1, 2),
                  value: 2
                },
                {
                  key: this.getUidFromSectionAndRow(1, 3),
                  value: 3
                }
              ], title: 'Section 1' },
              { data: [
                {
                  key: this.getUidFromSectionAndRow(2, 1),
                  value: 1
                },
                {
                  key: this.getUidFromSectionAndRow(2, 2),
                  value: 2
                },
                {
                  key: this.getUidFromSectionAndRow(2, 3),
                  value: 3
                }
              ], title: 'Section 2' },
            ]
          }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

This 70 lines of code should be simple enough, the key is to make every section / row reflect to an unique key in state.

So every time you set style with `setStyleWithUid()`, it only effects to that specific row.

Comment: umm sorry but this is not the problem that I am facing. If you will inspect rendered tree with react-devtools you will see, that your rendered view looks ok, but it is wrapped with full-width view generated by SectionList which is transparent. My problem was that I could not click anything UNDER that view. I've solved my problem by using `ScrollView` instead of `SectionList`. Additionally `VirtualizedList` in react 0.5 introduced property `cellRendererComponent` and finally you can pass your own custom component which would also resolve my issue